# Link Github Create Release button to a Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

So essentially the issue we have is that this button `Create a new release` doesn't take all the required steps that we have in our release workflow action.

What I'd like to do is either hide this button or link it to our release workflow instead of the default github release forum.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can trigger a workflow every time you create a release with the [release keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release). Wouldn't that link the button to your release workflow?

Comment: @GuiFalourd ah that might do the trick. I'll check it out here in a minute. Thank you

Comment: @GuiFalourd oh actually this doesn't work because our release action has required info that it needs filled in prior to running the action. We need version info. I think what you're suggesting would auto kick it off but doesn't prompt for those fields

Comment: Depending on what datas you need, it may be posaible to extract it from the workflow Github Context, or even using the Github API. Could you give more details? 

Comment: @GuiFalourd for sure. We're just trying to generate a release with a workflow that requires some custom build operations. So we collect the version number, if it's a pre-release or draft. That's essentially it

Comment: Ok. How do you manage version numbers? Are you using tags? Is it manual or automatic following semantic version?

Comment: It's manual semantic versioning

Comment: In that case, would it be an option to create the release automatically on the TAG creation? And extract the TAG version in your workflow if you need it for other custom build operations?

Comment: @GuiFalourd that may work. I'll give that a shot. Thanks